# Variable is used before it has been assigned Null Reference Exception

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble fixing this null reference exception

```
    Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim Trans As OleDb.OleDbTransaction

    Try
        ' create the stream writer object
        Dim FS As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName)

        ' open DB connection and start a transaction
        Dim Tmp As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter
        Conn.ConnectionString = Tmp.Connection.ConnectionString
        Conn.Open()
        Trans = Conn.BeginTransaction

        ' clear all tables
        Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD.CommandText = " delete from ReciptDetails"
        CMD.Connection = Conn
        CMD.Transaction = Trans
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD.Dispose()

        CMD = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD.CommandText = " delete from Recipts"
        CMD.Connection = Conn
        CMD.Transaction = Trans
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD.Dispose()

        CMD = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD.CommandText = " delete from items"
        CMD.Connection = Conn
        CMD.Transaction = Trans
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD.Dispose()

        CMD = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD.CommandText = " delete from RestorantTable"
        CMD.Connection = Conn
        CMD.Transaction = Trans
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD.Dispose()

        CMD = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        CMD.CommandText = " delete from [Values]"
        CMD.Connection = Conn
        CMD.Transaction = Trans
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CMD.Dispose()

        ' load the tables
        If Not LoadTableFromBackup(Conn, Trans, FS, "RestorantTable") Then
            Trans.Rollback()
            Conn.Close()
            FS.Close()
            Return False
        End If
        If Not LoadTableFromBackup(Conn, Trans, FS, "Values") Then
            Trans.Rollback()
            Conn.Close()
            FS.Close()
            Return False
        End If
        If Not LoadTableFromBackup(Conn, Trans, FS, "items") Then
            Trans.Rollback()
            Conn.Close()
            FS.Close()
            Return False
        End If
        If Not LoadTableFromBackup(Conn, Trans, FS, "Recipts") Then
            Trans.Rollback()
            Conn.Close()
            FS.Close()
            Return False
        End If
        If Not LoadTableFromBackup(Conn, Trans, FS, "ReciptDetails") Then
            Trans.Rollback()
            Conn.Close()
            FS.Close()
            Return False
        End If

        FS.Close()

        Trans.Commit()

        Conn.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trans.Rollback()
        Conn.Close()
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: Are you aware that your [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) contains quite a lot of information stored in [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception_properties.aspx) that you can query?

Comment: Trans.Rollback() i am not i am quite newbie but i like the difficult parts dont know really where to start i tried debugging this system but there is so many errors.

Comment: what daniel is saying is that the exception itself will tell you a lot about the error, esp the inner exception

Comment: Can you give us the content of your LoadTableFromBackup method ?

Comment: You are not checking whether `Trans` is null. It could be, and then you'd have the exception you mentioned in the title. Assuming it isn't, then the exception is thrown somewhere inside `Trans.Rollback()` - if I am to believe you. In this case the rest of the code you posted is totally useless. You could as well have posted the line `Trans.Rollback()` and asked why it might throw an exception from inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it would appear that `Trans` is never being assigned a value.  Take a look at a smaller sample of your code:

```
Try
    ' create the stream writer object
    Dim FS As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName)

    ' open DB connection and start a transaction
    Dim Tmp As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter
    Conn.ConnectionString = Tmp.Connection.ConnectionString
    Conn.Open()
    Trans = Conn.BeginTransaction

    ' the rest of the code...
Catch ex As Exception
    Trans.Rollback()
    Conn.Close()
    Return False
End Try
```

Your `Catch` block assumes that `Trans` and `Conn` will have values.  However, if an exception is thrown *before* the line `Trans = Conn.BeginTransaction` then `Trans` will never have been assigned a value, so it will be `null` (`Nothing` in VB).

What's happening here is that something *before* that line is throwing an exception.  But then your exception handler itself throws an entirely different exception.  This is essentially obscuring the first exception, which is the actual error you're trying to find.

Using a debugger, put a break point on `Trans.Rollback()` and see what that original exception is, that's something you'll need to correct.

Aside from that, you can re-structure your `Try/Catch` blocks a bit to not assume that variables have values.  Just to get you going as a beginner, at the very least you can do this in your `Catch` block:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    If Trans Is Not Nothing Then
        Trans.Rollback()
    End If
    If Conn Is Not Nothing Then
        Conn.Close()
    End If
    Return False
End Try
```

Comment: I am now getting a hang of it. thank you so much but one more question..
am i allowed to use not nothing ? since is operator does not accept operands of type integer ?

Comment: @user2863178: I'm not sure what you're asking there.  `Trans`, `Conn`, and `Nothing` should all be treated as reference types, not value types (such as `Integer`), so you should be able to compare them in this manner.

Comment: i used it and replace the codes of exception to your suggestion but i still got that error. maybe i still lack the basic skill to debug it or do i still need to start from scratch?

Comment: @user2863178: Are you sure it's the exact same error?  With the exact same cause?  This error was obscuring another error, maybe you're getting that one?  You said in another comment that "there are so many errors."  This is a good opportunity for you to step through the code in a debugger and, line by line, examine what it's doing and how the state of each variable is changed.  Any individual exception should have a (usually) useful error message and a stack trace indicating exactly which line threw the exception.

Comment: by the looks of that codes it still have many errors but the errors are all ambiguous and this is the only exception error i already look at it the program is running smooth but it still have an about 100+ ambiguous error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error. It's a warning because you use trans before assigning it. Move Conn.Open()
and Trans = Conn.BeginTransaction before try and you will solve it.